# Simple citation footnotes

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, footnotes, citing

I'm writing a paper and I would like to add some citations. I would like to put references (like [21]) in the text that, when clicked, point to the relevant link in the bibliography section at the end of the document.

EDIT: I'm trying to use bibtex. This is what I have, but I'm not seeing any bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{intro} % here's the ~\cite{Nobody06}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\bibliography{b}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 

\end{document}
```

And b.bib:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

Comment: Your example works for me. The bibliography appears. Are you sure that you compiled it properly?

Comment: Actually I did not. I didn't run the bibtex command from texmaker. This works now.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its default citation style you get citations with numbers in square brackets. To load biblatex with default settings use `\usepackage{biblatex}`. You make a reference by using `\cite` (or one of the other citation commands mentioned in [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). The reference/bibliography section is placed by `\printbibliography`.

To get clickable links you need to also load [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) with `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author  = {Donald E. Knuth},
    title   = {The {{\TeX}book}},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
    date    = {1984}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{texbook}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX for formating your references and the `\cite{}` function to cite a reference. 
Then, using the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks everything should be ok.